# MethodNotAllowedHttpException form error

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have created a form in Laravel so here are the following files:
The form that someone should submit some details, 
contact.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.layout')


@section('content')

    <main role="main">

      <section class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Laravel demo</h1>

          <p class="lead text-muted">Please fill the form</p>
          @if(count($errors) > 0)
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
               {{$error}}
              </div>

            @endforeach
          @endif

        </div>
      </section>

      <div class="album text-muted">
        <div class="container">


          {!! Form::open(['url' => 'contact/submit']) !!}
          {!! csrf_field() !!}
            <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
            {{Form::text('name', 'Enter Name', ['class'=> 'form-control'])}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address') }}
            {{Form::text('email', 'example@gmail.com', ['class'=> 'form-control'])}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('message', 'Enter Message') }}
            {{Form::textarea('message', 'Enter Message', ['class'=> 'form-control'])}}
            </div>
            <div>
            {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=> 'btn btn-primary'])}}
            </div>

          {!! Form::close() !!}

        </div>
      </div>

    </main>

@endsection
```

Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function submit(Request $request){

      $this->validate($request, [
          'name' => 'required',
          'email' => 'required'
      ]);

      return 'SUCCESS';
    }
}
```

*
In the Routes web.php file i have included the method as post:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
});

Route::post('/contact/submit', 'MessageController@submit');
```

The error message is " RouteCollection.php (line 251)" .After searching for similar occassions here the problem ussually occurs when in the Routes you use a different method to the specified route method. I'm using POST method for submiting details, I still cannot understand why I get this. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the browser console show? Is it using POST, is it sending to the right end point?

Comment: It was the page contact/submit that has the issue. if i press the submit button of the form in the /contact page it returns success also I haven't completed the method so this might be the reason! My apologies i'm new to Laravel

Comment: I dont follow. Have you watched the network request in your browser console when you submit the form or not?

Comment: Status is 200 and there are no errors in the console through the element inspection.

Comment: You are going to need to post more of the error

Comment: Inspect your `<form>` element; is it a `GET` or `POST`? To me, it looks like a `GET`, but I'm not sure of the output for `Form::open()`. I use `<form method="POST" action="{{ url("/contact/submit") }}">` (more control, personal preference) to ensure this isn't an issue. Regardless, you need to ensure you're `POST`ing to `Route::post("/contact/submit", ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this {!! Form::open(['url' => 'contact/submit']) !!}

Try this.

{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST','action'=>'MessageController@submit']) !!}

Answer (score -1):

Add the back slash to the url of the form like so :

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/contact/submit']) !!}
```

Comment: Try to pass the full url : http ://site.dev/contact/submit because your routing looks good to me

Comment: The problem remains